# vue-router change mode history i got problem blankpage when access child route such as "/order/callback"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

i got problem issue i'll change mode "hash" to "history" then i'm go url website to

localhost:8082/order    >>>>> it's okay

if i gone
localhost:8082/order/callback     >>>>>>>>>> it'll blank page

in my router set

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";

const $ROLE = getRole;

Vue.use(Router);

const router = new Router({
    mode: "history",
    linkExactActiveClass: "active",
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/order",
            name: "linetest",
            component: () => 
                import(/* webpackChunkName: "demo" */ "./views/LineLiff/CancelOrder.vue"),
            meta: {
                guest: true,
            },
        },
        {
            path: "/order/callback",
            name: "linetest",
            component: () => 
                import(/* webpackChunkName: "demo" */ "./views/LineLiff/CancelOrder.vue"),
            meta: {
                guest: true,
            },
        },
    ],
});

export default router;
```

help me this how to fix vue-router

Comment: You should not give the same name to both routes. Furthermore, I would suggest to nest subroutes into a parent element (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html). Whereas the first one might even solve your issue, the latter would rather be a cosmetic/structural thing to do.

Comment: Other than the same route names, I can't see any issue. The code should work as is. Maybe you can provide some more information.